# How to get all Html from web page by javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get HTML from web page from javascript or jquery.Can you guide me ?

Comment: you mean `document` keyword with `innerHTML`, like `var page = document.innerHTML;`

Comment: @Jai he means *all* the content, including `!doctype` too, I assume,

Comment: @Xero then `document.doctype + document.documentElement.outerHTML` this.

Comment: @Jai, nice, now make an answer.

Comment: @thanapat saeliu You should accept answer, If you got answer to your question. It is the correct way to behave and this way you will give appreciation back to people that put down effort into helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch HTML(including HTML tags) of page using:-

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

If you want `DOCTYPE` information as well, you can do this:-

```
document.doctype
```

Finally, add them together.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this doesn't fetch the `!DOCTYPE`.

Comment: @Xero - Yes it won't but OP didn't mentioned that explicitly either.

Comment: You're right, but it does say _all HTML_.  So I would assume the `!DOCTYPE` deceleration...  That's just me though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch complete HTML of page using

```
$(html).html();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayh96u7z/1/)**

Comment: Good answer, but this doesn't get the HTML tags, nor the `!DOCTYPE` delectation.

Comment: Do not forgot to accept/upvote when answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document` with this:

```
var page = document.doctype;
    page += document.documentElement.outerHTML;

console.log(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use `$(html)` to get whole page.

```
console.log($(html));
```

You'll see:  `Object[html]` is logged and click to `html` then you'd know it's whole html.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using simple javascript

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

will give you html of full page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
alert(markup);
```